# JavaScript change event on input[type="file"]

Tags: javascript, html, input

I programmed a script: The user can click the Browse button and a dialog box will open. Once the user has selected what you want to create a list of selected files. Duplicates may also be allowed.

My problem is that I work with `change` event. That is when the user selects a file and the files end up in my list, and the user wants to select the same file again does not work.

Example

```
jQuery(form).find("input[type='file']").on("change", checkSelectedFile);

function checkSelectedFile (e) { console.log(e); }
```

If first and last files are the same then the event is not fired. Do you have an idea?

Comment: Well, then it simply isn't a change, just like with a `select` element that you open and select the same `option` again. I don't know your exact use case, but maybe you can use `focus` and `blur` for the input?

Answer (score 0):

If the same file is selected, than there is no change so it is impossible for onchange to fire. You probably want to use `blur`.

Comment: thanks guys
I have a solution i can change the value in Event Hanlder with jQuery(e.currentTarget).val("");